# explain Hibernate query cache

Tags: java, hibernate, caching

I read the article in http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t48846.html which explain Hibernate Query Cache but I couldn't completely understand how it works.

As the article explain:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("from Person as p where p.parent.id=? and p.firstName=?");
query.setInt(0, Integer.valueOf(1));
query.setString(1, "Joey");
query.setCacheable(true);
List l = query.list();
```

*The query cache works something like this:*

```
*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*
|                                    Query Cache                                         |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| ["from Person as p where p.parent.id=? and p.firstName=?", [ 1 , "Joey"] ] -> [  2 ] ] |
*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*
```

*The combination of the query and the values provided as parameters to that query is used as a key, and the value is the list of **identifiers** for that query.*

**Question 1**: What are **identifiers** in this? Are they the entities' ID in query result?

**Question 2:** Hibernate's documents say

> For example, if you cache results of a query against an object,
>   Hibernate needs to keep track of whether any changes have been
>   committed against the object, and invalidate the cache accordingly

If the answer for question 1 is YES(they are the entities' ID in query result), Does this mean the cached keep timestamps when a table was last updated and decide to refresh cache if needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes.
2. The cache keeps track of which tables a given cache entry is dependent on. When any of these tables are updated (any row or rows, whether or not they affect a particular cached result), the cache entry is invalidated. This means that the next time that query+parameters happens again, it will result in a database query rather than pulling the result from the query cache.

Comment: How cache recognizes something changes in DB? Does it use timestamp?

Comment: The "how" is an implementation detail that you don't need to know. However, having a timestamp on the cached query results and a last-updated timestamp for each table would not be an unreasonable way to support this functionality. Another option would be to invalidate all cache entries that are affected by each update as it occurs.